# Export DESCRIBE TABLE Postgres to .txt file with PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Is it possible to generate a .txt file with the DESCRIBE TABLE from a table in Postgres by PHP? I need to download a .txt file with the description of the fields (name, type, character size) of the table where the query is being made.

Comment: isn't `describe` an oracle command?..

Comment: Yes. In this case would be equivalent of “describe table” in postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run smth like:

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name ='s100';
```

it will definetely give you info on  (name, type, character size)

And if you want smth more wide, like oracles `DESC`, run `psql -E` in terminal and then `\d+ your_table` to see queries you need to use to get additional info